# How to list all object's versions from a bucket and their respective metadata (x-amz-meta-version)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

to achieve what's in the title I am trying to do a couple steps (using python & AWS SDK), which I will list after I mention the error I am getting is 412 "At least one of the preconditions you specified did not hold" in the second iteration of the method get_object, when I send it the parameters: bucket, key and IfMatch (it fails in this line).

List all object's versions with the following code

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_object_versions(
                    Bucket='my-bucket',
                    Prefix='file.exe'
                )
obj_versions = response["Versions"]
```

This totally works, but I need the versions I set in metadata (x-amz-meta-version), to get each object's metadata version I am trying to do the following:

```
obj_info = []
for obj_version in obj_versions:
    obj = s3.get_object(
            Bucket='my-bucket',
            Key='file.exe',
            IfMatch=obj_version['ETag']
        )
    obj_info.append(obj['Metadata']['version'])
```

And that's it, at the moment it only works until the second iteration oddly enough, it always fails with a 412 "At least one of the preconditions you specified did not hold" in the s3.get_object (IfMatch) line. I know for sure the error is in the precondition IfMatch, but I have no idea what's wrong... I have printed every ETag it's receiving and they're all valid, it should be able to get the object.
​
Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`s3.get_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) tries retrieve the *current version* of the object unless you include `VersionId` of another version, so the behavior you are observing is correct -- the ETag of the current version does not match the etag value that you're passing, and thus the precondition fails.  ETag isn't a lookup key, and IfMatch isn't a selector (it's a conditional request -- "don't give me the object unless the precondition matches") and in any event, multiple versions of an object can have the same ETag if the object versions have identical payload (depending on the type of encryption you are using on the bucket -- the standard only requires etags to differ if payload differs; it does not technically require them to match if the payload matches).

Note also that if you only want the metadata, then for both cost and performance reasons you should use [`s3.head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) to avoid fetching the object payload.

Comment: I wasn't aware ETag worked like that or what it was for that matter. Thank you for the information and suggestion!

Comment: Internet RFC-7232 has sections detailing the underlying theory and practice of [`ETag`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3) and [`If-Match`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-3.1).  Not everything there is necessarily applicable to S3 but you may find it informative.

Comment: Very nice info, I learnt many things that were throwing me off, thanks for the links!